# Cant resolve setLevel on HttpLoggingInterceptor Retrofit2.0

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I am using Retrofit and I want to log my response and other things, I am using this https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-log-requests-and-responses type but I am facing **Cant resolve setLevel** error

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();  

logging.setLevel(Level.BODY); // i am getting error on this

OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();  

httpClient.addInterceptor(logging); //this is also getting error
```

I am using this
*compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'* and Retrofit
*compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'* dependency.

[image: This is where i got error]

Comment: Hi, can you post a screenshot of the error you're getting? I'm going to take a guess and say that you might have your own Level class in your project. Try `logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)` and see if it works.

Comment: @lemuel Hay i have attach screenshots can you suggest me whats the problem?

Comment: What's your Retrofit version? Can you paste the dependency declaration?

Comment: @lemuel i have already mention

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Write your `interceptor` code inside the `getClient()` method like

```
public class RestClient {

    public getClient() {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
 }
}
```

Comment: Well this worked for me. But can you add an explanation?

Answer (score 13):

Add this dependency to your app's gradle:

```
 compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'
```

And use it like below:
Build your `OkHttpClient` like below:

```
final OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
okHttpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(interceptor);
okHttpClientBuilder.connectTimeout(RestConstants.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
return okHttpClientBuilder.build();
```

And set it to your `Retrofit` as Client.

I recommend you to check if your app is `Debuggable` and than set your log interceptor. So in production you'll not log api results.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using okhttp3, make sure you import the **okhttp3**(instead of **okhttp**) logging:

change

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:3.14.1'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.14.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
define following plugins of retrofit in build.gradle(Mobile:app) correctly as show below...

dependencies {
 ..........
   implementation('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0')
            {
                exclude module: 'okhttp'
            }
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'
}

Works For Sure....@Ambilpura Sunil
```

Answer (score 0):

Great answer from https://stackoverflow.com/users/5316836/pitty 
Just wanted to provide more code to explain how to link the answer with Retrofit.Builder

```
public class RestClient {
    public OkHttpClient getClient() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(logging)
                .build();


        return client;
    }
}

RestClient rc = new RestClient();

private NetworkService() {
    mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(rc.getClient())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with this way, My problem solve with:-

```
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logg = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logg.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.addInterceptor(logg);
```